# Reset 3ds Max 2017 keyboard shortcuts to default

Tags: 3dsmax

I somehow messed up my keyboard shortcuts for 3ds Max 2017. How can I restore them to the default? Is there a default shortcut file I can restore them with?

I'm aware there's a *Reset* button inside the Keyboard options, but my 3ds Max crashes when I hit that button.

Comment: According to [this page](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/3DSMax/files/GUID-AA42E927-3598-48E1-895C-5F09AF387C3C-htm.html) there should be a button there called "Reset" that resets the keybindings to their default values?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 3ds Max keeps on crashing when pressing that button.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t worry. I’ve found out how to fix this. I just searched for .kbdx files in 3ds Max Program Files folder and used the one that was called DefaultUI and was in En-US folder. Thanks for trying.

Comment: I'm glad you managed to sort this out! Thanks for coming back to provide the solution you found.